# Making a matrix of column means

Tags: r

I have a vector of column means from my data, which looks as follows:

```
cmean <- c(v1=50.99013605,  v2=13.27823129, v3=67.83265306, v4=25.88299320)

    v1             v2              v3              v4 
    50.99013605    13.27823129     67.83265306     25.88299320
```

Then I want to make a matrix out of it, in which all the columns are just duplicates of the column means. Hence I want it to look like this:

```
    50.99013605    13.27823129     67.83265306     25.88299320 
    50.99013605    13.27823129     67.83265306     25.88299320 
    50.99013605    13.27823129     67.83265306     25.88299320 
    50.99013605    13.27823129     67.83265306     25.88299320
```

I tried a lot using `rep`, but I failed putting it nicely in this format in a matrix. What is the handiest way to do this?

Comment: In case you start with a data.frame and want to turn all rows of each column into the column's means, you can use `df[] <- lapply(df, mean)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can assign the dimensions with `dim<-` after replicating 'v1' using the `col`.

```
`dim<-`(v1[col(d2)], dim(d2))
#         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]
#[1,] 50.99014 13.27823 67.83265 25.88299
#[2,] 50.99014 13.27823 67.83265 25.88299
#[3,] 50.99014 13.27823 67.83265 25.88299
#[4,] 50.99014 13.27823 67.83265 25.88299
```

Or use `replicate`

```
do.call(rbind, replicate(nrow(d2), v1, simplify=FALSE))
#        v1       v2       v3       v4
#[1,] 50.99014 13.27823 67.83265 25.88299
#[2,] 50.99014 13.27823 67.83265 25.88299
#[3,] 50.99014 13.27823 67.83265 25.88299
#[4,] 50.99014 13.27823 67.83265 25.88299
```

---

Or a compact option is

```
(d2/d2)*v1[col(d2)]
```

---

If we are using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
d2 %>%
    mutate_each(funs(mean))
```

where 'd2' is the initial dataset and 'v1' its column means.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `byrow` argument to `matrix`. For example:

```
> x <- 1:4
> matrix(x, 4, 4, TRUE)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    1    2    3    4
[3,]    1    2    3    4
[4,]    1    2    3    4
```

If you don't pass in the `TRUE` then it fills the matrix in by column by default:

```
> matrix(x, 4, 4)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3    3
[4,]    4    4    4    4
```

Comment: IMHO this is the easiest solution, but you should use TRUE and not T since nothing in R blocks this redefinition: `T<-FALSE` and after that anything may happen... ;)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with `rep()`

```
cmean <- c(v1=50.99013605,  v2=13.27823129, v3=67.83265306, v4=25.88299320)
M <- 5 # number of rows
matrix(rep(cmean, each=M), M)
#> matrix(rep(cmean, each=M), M)
#         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]
#[1,] 50.99014 13.27823 67.83265 25.88299
#[2,] 50.99014 13.27823 67.83265 25.88299
#[3,] 50.99014 13.27823 67.83265 25.88299
#[4,] 50.99014 13.27823 67.83265 25.88299
#[5,] 50.99014 13.27823 67.83265 25.88299
```

If you want to copy the names you can do:

```
x <- matrix(rep(cmean, each=M), M)
colnames(x) <- names(cmean)
```

Comment: Since the names are getting dropped anyway, you might as well go with `rep.int()` for speed.